# C# RichTextBox no guarda imagenes

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Estoy desarrollando un **RichTextBox**, en el que puedo añadir tipos de letra, colores, negritas, y imágenes. Hasta aquí todo correcto, el problema es que al grabar no guarda las imágenes, pero si los tipos de letra y colores.

Me he dado cuenta que al ver el archivo con Bloc de notas no aparece nada que haga referencia a la imagen.

Cuando lo edito queda de esta forma, pero cuando lo recupero se pierde la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilizo para guardar lo editado es el siguiente:

```
    if (!File.Exists(ruta + nombreArchivo))
                {       
                    //escribir el archivo.
                    dynamicRichTextBox.SaveFile(ruta + nombreArchivo, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichNoOleObjs);
                    
                } else
                { 

                    dynamicRichTextBox.SaveFile(ruta + nombreArchivo, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichNoOleObjs); // Modifica el archivo el archivo.
                    
                }
```

No sé si está correcto y es el motivo de que no guarde las imágenes. Se agradece una ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser que la estructura de la ruta que insertas no es correcta, tendría que ser la siguiente:

```
if (!File.Exists(ruta + nombreArchivo)) {       
//escribir el archivo.
dynamicRichTextBox.SaveFile(ruta + "/" + nombreArchivo, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichNoOleObjs);
}
else {
// Modifica el archivo el archivo.
dynamicRichTextBox.SaveFile(ruta + "/" + nombreArchivo, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichNoOleObjs);                  
}
```

Comment: No, la ruta está correcta. Lo he podido solucionar cambiando tan solo RichTextBoxStreamType.RichNoOleObjs por esta otra RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText No me había dado cuenta que RichNoOleObjs no guarda objetos, tal como indica en su propio nombre. Gracias de todas formas.